# How to use NVIDIA K80?

Tags: cuda

The machine has 4 NVIDIA K80s setuped and the outputs of `nvidia-smi` are the information of the 4 cards. Their GPU IDs are `0,1,2,3`. Each K80 have two types of GPU memory: `FB` and `BAR1`, both have 12 Gb. But the CUDA programs always use the `FB` memory, with the `BAR1` memory left be free. When the CUDA programs allocate more than 12 Gb GPU memory in each card, an error of `Out of memory` will be occurred, but the `BAR1` memory still be not used.

How could I use the `BAR1` memory correctly in this setting?

**UPDATED**
The partial output of `nvidia-smi` is

```
      Compute Mode:
         < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >
    > Peer access from Tesla K80 (GPU0) -> Tesla K80 (GPU1) : Yes
    > Peer access from Tesla K80 (GPU0) -> Tesla K80 (GPU2) : No
    > Peer access from Tesla K80 (GPU0) -> Tesla K80 (GPU3) : No
    > Peer access from Tesla K80 (GPU1) -> Tesla K80 (GPU0) : Yes
    > Peer access from Tesla K80 (GPU1) -> Tesla K80 (GPU2) : No
    > Peer access from Tesla K80 (GPU1) -> Tesla K80 (GPU3) : No
    > Peer access from Tesla K80 (GPU2) -> Tesla K80 (GPU0) : No
    > Peer access from Tesla K80 (GPU2) -> Tesla K80 (GPU1) : No
    > Peer access from Tesla K80 (GPU2) -> Tesla K80 (GPU3) : Yes
    > Peer access from Tesla K80 (GPU3) -> Tesla K80 (GPU0) : No
    > Peer access from Tesla K80 (GPU3) -> Tesla K80 (GPU1) : No
    > Peer access from Tesla K80 (GPU3) -> Tesla K80 (GPU2) : Yes
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the man pages of nvidia-smi:

```
BAR1 Memory Usage
       BAR1 is used to map the FB (device memory) so that it can  be  directly
       accessed  by  the CPU or by 3rd party devices (peer-to-peer on the PCIe
       bus).
```

BAR1 is a virtual address space that maps the device memory for DMA access from the host and/or other DMA enabled devices. 
This means that BAR1 is not physical memory and your K80 (as said in the specs) only has 12 GB VRAM for each GK210B GPU. When this memory is depleted you are really out-of-memory.

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying!  I've updated the post with the output of `nvidia-smi`, please kindly check it. From these outputs, if I understood correctly, it seems there are only two physical K80s. GPU0 and GPU1 belong to the first K80; GPU2 and GPU3 belong to the other K80. Is it right?

Comment: I've tried to use these four devices in a multi-GPU program. In this program, it has some data transfer between these cards. As shown in the CUDA Examples, the data transfer has two types: with P2P and without P2P. In the program, we should check whether the cards have P2P and UVA with each other. If yes, we could use `cudaMemcpyDefault`; If no, we should first copy data to CPU memory from the source GPU and then copy to the target GPU.

Comment: I have set `P2P` be enabled, but the `BAR1` memory seems to be still not used. It alwarys shows "BAR1 Memory Usage
        Total                       : 16384 MiB
        Used                        : 6 MiB
        Free                        : 16378 MiB
    Compute Mode                    : Default"

Comment: In fact, I never saw a physical K80 card. The machine is one computing node in a small cluster. I don't know how many cards have been setup in the machine.

Comment: The output certainly looks like two physical cards each with two devices. It is not clear from your follow-on comments whether you are asking any particular question.

Comment: @void_ptr, thank you for replying! Yes, I have enabled the P2P accesses among the four devices. If I understood correctly, the `BAR1` memory should be used.

Comment: @mining I am not an expert on the BAR1 metric form nvidia-smi but I think enabling P2P across devices does not influence it. You have to change the way you allocate memory. Maybe using cudaMallocHost is what you need.

Comment: @MichaelHaidl, thank you very much for your advice! If I understood correctly, `cudaMallocHost` will allocate the pinned host memory. And in my multi-GPU code, I use `pthread` to control different GPU devices. When I use `cudaMallocHost` in different threads, and the data transfer between them seems to have problem. Thus I change `cudaMallocHost` to `malloc` to exchange the data. If the two devices have P2P access, then the problem won't exist, just use `cudaMemcpyDefault`.